# too many measurments in the input buffer in rplidar

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I am using a RPLidar A1 in python. 
it looks pretty perfect and this is my code below
it is originally from https://github.com/SkoltechRobotics/rplidar/blob/master/examples/animate.py#L1
GitHub.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''Animates distances and measurment quality'''
from rplidar import RPLidar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

PORT_NAME = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
DMAX = 4000
IMIN = 0
IMAX = 50

def update_line(num, iterator, line):
    scan = next(iterator)
    offsets = np.array([(np.radians(meas[1]), meas[2]) for meas in scan])
    line.set_offsets(offsets)
    intens = np.array([meas[0] for meas in scan])
    line.set_array(intens)
    return line,

def run():
    lidar = RPLidar(PORT_NAME)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax  = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
    line = ax.scatter([0, 0], [0, 0], s=5, c=[IMIN, IMAX],
                           cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, lw=0)
    ax.set_rmax(DMAX)
    ax.grid(True)

    iterator = lidar.iter_scans()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line,
        fargs=(iterator, line), interval=50)
    plt.show()
    lidar.stop()
    lidar.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

but it has issues like this picture.[image]

I think that it is because of something buffer. But no idea how to handle this one. if you help me about this issues, I really appreciate of it.
I have no idea why this is happened please let me know Thank you!

Comment: hi, did you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the RPLidar documentation: https://github.com/SkoltechRobotics/rplidar/blob/master/rplidar.py

The `iter_scans()` [and `iter_measurments()`] functions have a default parameter of `max_buf_meas`. This defaults to 500. It looks like you're filling this buffer too quickly.

I suggest giving the `iter_scans()` call a buffer argument that is greater than the number your program is giving you, perhaps 800 or 1000.

Comment: increasing the buffer size will only delay the problem, unless the scan is very limited in time (a few seconds). And I agree with the op, because I used the lidar on 2 very powerful computers and a very basic script, with one I had no problem, and the other kept making this buffer warning. Something to do with the USB port... don't know.